# juju error: certificate expired/not-valid

Tags: juju, maas, certificates

On Ubuntu 14.04, I'm seeing below errors in juju machine log after deploying a juju charm for nova-compute :

```
2014-08-18 06:50:42 ERROR juju apiclient.go:119 state/api: websocket.Dial wss://bootstrap.maas:17070/: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
2014-08-18 06:50:42 ERROR juju runner.go:220 worker: exited "api": websocket.Dial wss://bootstrap.maas:17070/: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
```

How can I fix this error?

juju version: 1.18.1-0ubuntu1

Comment: Could this be an example of https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1352944?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was fixed by setting the time zone of the machine/n to be same as MAAS server